ARCore resolve cloud anchor unity giving `ErrorIllegalState` && `ErrorInternal`
When running the method aRAnchorManager.ResolveCloudAnchorAsync(cloudAnchorId).
I receive the error Failed to resolve a new Cloud Anchor async, status 'ErrorIllegalState'. And the AnchorState is ErrorInternal.
I can host an anchor using the API key and get a cloud id. However when trying to resolve the anchor id in a different app I get the above error. The TTL of cloud id is not the problem same with the key. I have made sure it is setup on every setting (Player settings and ARCoreExtension file).
Also, I checked the google cloud API and there are no requests (only for adding which includes a Get for some reason). Furthermore I ensured networking was allowed and am still getting the error
Here is the methods i am currently using
update.
void Update()
    {
        // if (ARCoreExtensionsConfig.CloudAnchorMode != CloudAnchorMode.Enabled)
        // {
        //     Debug.Log("Cloud anchor not enabled");
        //     return;
        // }
        if (allAnchors.Count == cloudIds.Count)
        {
            Debug.Log("All anchors are loaded");
            return;
        }
        if (isResolving)
        {
            Debug.Log("Already resolving");
            return;
        }
        if (ARSession.state != ARSessionState.SessionTracking)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not ready");
            isResolving = false;
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            isResolving = true;
            InitalLoad();
            isResolving = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            isResolving = false;
        }

    }

and here is the method to resolve it.
private async Task<ARCloudAnchor> ResolveCloudAnchor(string cloudAnchorId)
    {
        Debug.Log("Resolving cloud anchor... " + cloudAnchorId);

        ResolveCloudAnchorPromise cloudAnchorPromise = aRAnchorManager.ResolveCloudAnchorAsync(cloudAnchorId);
        while (cloudAnchorPromise.State == PromiseState.Pending)
        {
            await Task.Yield(); // Yield control to avoid blocking the main thread
        }
        ResolveCloudAnchorResult res = cloudAnchorPromise.Result;
        // Validate the cloud anchor state
        if (res.CloudAnchorState == CloudAnchorState.Success)
        {
            return res.Anchor;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Cloud Anchor resolving failed with state: {res.CloudAnchorState}");
            return null;
        }

    }

Any help would be great thanks and here is the full error
Failed to resolve a new Cloud Anchor async, status 'ErrorIllegalState'
Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.Internal.SessionApi:ResolveCloudAnchorAsync(IntPtr, String)
Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.ARAnchorManagerExtensions:ResolveCloudAnchorAsync(ARAnchorManager, String)
<ResolveCloudAnchor>d__11:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:Start(TStateMachine&)
<PlaceInitalAnchorsAndMesh>d__7:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start(TStateMachine&)
ARCloudAnchorManager:PlaceInitalAnchorsAndMesh()

Res is Google.XR.ARCoreExtensions.ResolveCloudAnchorResult
Cloud Anchor resolving failed with state: ErrorInternal
<ResolveCloudAnchor>d__11:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:Start(TStateMachine&)
<PlaceInitalAnchorsAndMesh>d__7:MoveNext()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder:Start(TStateMachine&)

